# filling a List<List<>> with f#

Tags: list, f#

I need a function that returns a List < List < T>>. 
The value i j should be 1.0 or 2.0 or nothing..depending on certain conditions (condition_1_is_true ...).

I've written the following :

```
type T = 
  {
     value : float32
  }
let level_1_docked_balls : List<List<T>>=
    [ for i in 0 .. LineNumber - 1->
        [ for j  in 0 .. BallsPerLine - 1 ->

            if (condition_1_is_true) then
                {
                   value = 1.0f
                }
            elif (condition_2_is_true) then
                {
                    value = 2.0f
                }
            else
                //HERE I don't know how to return nothing

        ]
    ]
```

The problem is that in certain cases (else branch), I need to return nothing, but I don't know how to do it.

NOTE: I know that there are eventually better ways to initialize a List but I would like to understand how to make the above example work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
let level_1_docked_balls : List<List<option<float32>>> = 
    [ for i in 0 .. LineNumber - 1 -> 
        [ for j  in 0 .. BallsPerLine - 1 -> 
            if (condition_1_is_true) then Some 1.0f 
            elif (condition_2_is_true) then Some 2.0f 
            else None ]  ]
```

There is no way to say that there is *nothing* at a specified index in the list. A list is simply a list of values and if you didn't return a value, then the list would be shorter. If you want to represent `float` or nothing, then you can use F# `option` type - the value `Some 1.0f` specifies that there is a value 1.0f and the value `None` specifies that there is no number at that position.

I also changed the type from `float` to `float32` in the type annotation. The type `float32` corresponds to `System.Single` and the literals are written as `1.0f`. The other option is double (`float` with literals `1.0`).

As a side-note, if you're representing some 2D matrix and especially if you need to access value at a specified index, then it is probably better to use 2D array. Although they are mutable, you can use them in an immutable way using higher-order functions like `Array2D.map`. To create a 2D array similar to your list, you could write:

```
let level1 = Array2D.init LineNumber BallsPerLine (fun i j ->
  if (condition_1_is_true) then Some 1.0f 
  elif (condition_2_is_true) then Some 2.0f 
  else None)
```

**EDIT** There are two options to represent something like balls in a map of a game. Either use *dense* representation where you have some value for each *(i, j)* - that's what I described earlier. Another option is to use *sparse* representation where you only keep a list of balls, together with the *(i, j)* index where the ball is located. Then you could write something like:

```
let level_1_docked_balls : List<int * int * float32> = 
    [ for i in 0 .. LineNumber - 1 do
        for j  in 0 .. BallsPerLine - 1 do
          if (condition_1_is_true) then yield (i, j, 1.0f)
          elif (condition_2_is_true) then yield (i, j, 2.0f) ]
```

When you use `do` in the `for` loop, then you can write `yield` to generate an element, but you don't have to return a value in *each* case -- there is no `else` branch. However, you need to know the index where the value belongs.

Comment: ok..you have been quite clear. So I need to refactor my method because I'm using i and j values in the conditional check, but I don't want to use Option.

Comment: and look at my post. I edited because there was an error. Actually I need a List<List<T>>. Anyway, I'd rather not to use Option as already said, because the function who use level_1_docked_balls expects a List<List<T>> as return, not option.

Comment: @Heisenbug I added another option that uses a different representation where you don't need `option`. However, these are really the two only options, so I don't think you can achieve what you want using just `list<list<'T>>`.

Comment: thank you so much. It seems like you are reading my thoughts! Actually I first wrote a sparse representation. Then I changed it with a 2D array because I need to access an element's neighborhood, and with a 2d array seems simpler. I posted this question just for curiosity: I'm learning F# these days and still have some doubts.. thank you so much for your help.